# unable to move an image from temp folder

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image and then copy it in uploads folder in my directory but after uploading it will give this error for moving part:

> error 1 : Warning: move_uploaded_file(my photo path): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\Xamp\htdocs\a.php on line 55
>
> error 2 : Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'E:\Xamp\tmp\php369E.tmp' to 'my photo path' in E:\Xamp\htdocs\a.php on line 5

i checked my upload_max_size and fix it.

```
$target_dir = "Uploads Aks/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file , PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// actual or fake
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "file is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else{
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if ($uploadOk == 0){
    echo "sorry File did not uploaded";
}else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] , $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) . "has been uploaded";
    }else {
        echo "sorry, there was an error uploading your file";
    }
}
```

Comment: check folder permission

Comment: `my photo path`?? What do you think you are protecting here? Show the FULL real message please

Comment: If you removed the space from this folder name `Uploads Aks` would it work then?

Comment: ___Big Note___ Taken from [the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) ___Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.___

Comment: _SMall Point_ Putting `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` in a message to the user makes no sense. That is the name of the temp file on the server disk and will look like `jhsgdf.tmp` i.e. nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

Check the Target dir and try again. The problem is the space between the your path name

Instead of

```
 $target_dir = "Uploads Aks/uploads/";
```

Try

```
 $target_dir = "Uploads_Aks/uploads/";
```

Comment: Then they would have to change the ACTUAL folder name unless this is a simple misspelling of the folder name. Which is basically what I suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588314/unable-to-move-an-image-from-temp-folder#comment101634291_57588314)

Comment: No  **_** underscore will change actual file name to another name. We use `%20` instead of `space` in URLs